# How to declare a series of variable such as from x1 to xi in vba

Tags: excel, declare

In vba if using Option `Explicit` all variables need to be declared.

However, if I have a lot of variables that I'd like to name such as `x1`, `x2`, `x3` ... `xi`, so from the naming the common `x` makes them related (as opposed to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`...)

When seeing them a human would know that they all belong to `x`, but is there any way to let vba know by just declaring `x` once for all `x1`, `x2`...? Instead of

```
Dim x1 as double, x2 as double, x3 as double...
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Use better naming first of all, and then use an array. DIM DiscriptiveNameX(100) as double.

Answer (score 2):

Declare an array. Unlike [vb-script](/questions/tagged/vb-script) or [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) you cannot make declarations or assignments by concatenating values.

```
'this does not work
dim i as long
for i=1 to 99
    dim x & i as double
    x & i = i * 1.5
next i

'this works
dim i as long, x as variant
i=99
redim x(1 to i)

for i=lbound(x) to ubound(x)
    x(i) = i * 1.5
next i

for i=lbound(x) to ubound(x)
    debug.print x(i)
next i
```

Comment: That (concatenation) doesn't work in vbscript either. Or ASP-classic (which is/was typically vbscript)

Comment: Perhaps not now, but I'm pretty sure I used it (on-the-fly declaration and assignment only, no Dim'ming) in [tag:asp-classic] in the latter portion of the 20th century before I recognized just how atrocious the method was.Tho only reason I remember is that I was so totally amazed it actually worked.

Comment: VBscript has `Eval()` which is sort-of that.  That was a long time ago though, as you note.  Having said that, I admit to still using ASP classic so I can use server-side js.